# Changing properties of Java Window Objects inside action listeners

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I have been using WindowBuilder in Eclipse, and have added an action listener to a button (`btn1`).

I want this to set the "Enabled" property of another button (`btn2`) to true.

The code I currently have is:

```
JButton btn1 = new JButton("Enable btn2");
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            btn2.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    toolBar.add(btn1);

JButton btn2 = new JButton("Click btn1!");
    btn2.setEnabled(false);
    toolBar.add(btn2);
```

(The code above is inside a toolbar called `toolBar`).

The only problem is, that I want to run the actionPerformed() code in btn1, but it doesn't allow me to interact with btn2. I have tried putting the code after btn2's declaration, but I still get the following compile error:

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable btnStop inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

How do I interact with the btn2 button?

Comment: I've worked out the answer - make it final - but I need a exlanation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do just what the error message is telling you to do: make btn2 a final local variable:

```
final JButton btn2 = new JButton("Click btn1!");
```

Your problem is that you are trying to manipulate a local variable inside of an inner class, and that is not allowed unless the variable is declared final. Local variables are copied and then passed into the inner class, and if they are not final there is a chance that the local variable might change value (here meaning it would refer to another JButton), and the inner class's representation of the variable would not change with it.

Another option is to declare btn2 as a private non-static class field.

---

**Edit**
As was well stated by @AaronDavidson in comment:

> final means the variable won't ever change, which means it is safe for the anonymous inner class to keep a reference to the object, and later when the callback is executed, the reference will still be valid.

Comment: What does `final` do to allow this? Is there a reason that it must be final? I was hesitant to follow the quick-fix advice as I didn't understand what it meant.

Comment: final means the variable won't ever change, which means it is safe for the anonymous inner class to keep a reference to the object, and later when the callback is executed, the reference will still be valid.

Comment: @AaronDavidson: couldn't say it better myself. Thanks! I hope you don't mind that I borrowed your comment and placed it in my answer.